# Adding a coroutine with a webcam feed to a running asyncio loop stops tasks from running

Tags: python, python-asyncio, video-capture, opencv

If I run 1+n async greeting loops everything works fine. Whenever I add the runCamera method, it stops the greeting loops from running. Why is this happening? Or is this rather a case for threading? I want the greeting loops to run and the webcam image showing at the same time.

```
    def main():
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        asyncio.ensure_future(greet_every_two_seconds())
        asyncio.ensure_future(runCamera())
        loop.run_forever()

    async def greet_every_two_seconds():
        while True:
          print('Hello World')
          await asyncio.sleep(1)

    async def runCamera():
        vid = cv.VideoCapture(0)

        while (True):
           ret, frame = vid.read()
          cv.imshow('frame', frame)
           if cv.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
               break

        vid.release()
        cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Your runCamera function does not contain any `await` expression.  Therefore once the event loop gives it control, it will keep control until the end of the function.  All other coroutines are stopped, including `greet_every_two_seconds`.  It never yields back to the loop.  Just putting async in front of a def function isn't enough to make it cooperate with other tasks.  If the webcam's API doesn't contain functions that support asyncio, you need to use threads (as in ill's answer).

Comment: `cap.read()` will block traditionally. when you use async/await, you need code that __works with__ async/await, instead of blocking traditionally. this is not specific to OpenCV or VideoCapture. there surely are generic solutions that run traditionally blocking code in a separate thread and somehow convey the information through a queue into async/await-using routines. there is `asyncio.Queue`. -- NOTE: waitKey blocks too, so you should strongly reconsider even using async/await here at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a matter of threading and my guess is that that is due to: Threading provides thread-based concurrency, suitable for blocking I/O tasks - Asyncio doesnt.

Solution based on the two methods shown above (greet_every_two_seconds and runCamera) looks like this:

```
def main():
    server = threading.Thread(target=start_cam, daemon=True)
    server.start()
    client = threading.Thread(target=client_call)
    client.start()
    client.join()


def start_greeting():
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    asyncio.ensure_future(greet_every_two_seconds())
    loop.run_forever()

def start_cam():
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    asyncio.ensure_future(runCamera())
    loop.run_forever()
```